# Jquery autocomplete not showing the list even the data is returned properly in json format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

my jquery autocomplete is just ran properly before this, but suddenly it is not functioning and not displaying the data returned from my database. I could not figure out what is actually caused the problem. Maybe anyone can help..

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
source:'vot/handle_vot.php?p=find_vot', 
    minLength:3,
    dataType: "json",
    select: function( event, ui ) {        
        event.preventDefault();
        if (ui.item.value!=null) {                                  
            $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#vote_display" ).val( ui.item.value );
        } 
      },
    // optional
    html: true, 
    // optional (if other layers overlap the autocomplete list)
    open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1061);
    }
   // appendTo : modalAddPub                
}, "json");
```

when i run the script, the result returned as below in the chrome developer tools under network section...

```
 <meta http-equiv=refresh content='2; url=../index.php?page=allocation&vot=&tahun='>{
"0":{"value":"59300","label":"59300-Siti Salina Abdullah Dr. "},"1":{"value":"59301","label":"59301-Khatijah Omar Dr."},
"2":{"value":"59302","label":"59302-Hafiza Aishah Hashim (Dr. )"},
"3":{"value":"59303","label":"59303-Roshaiza Taha Dr. "},
"4":{"value":"59304","label":"59304-Nor Raihan Mohamad Dr. "},
"5":{"value":"59305","label":"59305-Ibrahim Mamat Prof. Dr. "},
"6":{"value":"59306","label":"59306-Tengku Sifzizul Tengku Muhammad Prof. Dr. "},
"7":{"value":"59307","label":"59307-Abol Munafi Ambok Bolong (Prof. Madya Dr.) "},
"8":{"value":"59308","label":"59308-Chuah Tse Seng (Prof. Madya Dr. )"},
"9":{"value":"59309","label":"59309-Mariam Taib (Prof. Madya Dr. )"},
"10":{"value":"59310","label":"59310-Hazlina Ahamad Zakeri  (Dr.)"}}
```

[image]

Comment: as per you telling that **my jquery autocomplete is just ran properly before this** and after that nothing you change then run project after clear history, cookies, etc which store temp. data or run this project in a private window.

Comment: its still not working...already clear cache n cookies...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning JSON from the server; you are returning a meta tag with JSON like string as text-content.

You need to either extract the string on the client or remove the meta tag before the content is sent.